# Label not changing when set programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view with a custom cell class and .xib that I'm initializing in my main view controller. In the custom cell class I have created a few IBOutlets that link to some labels and I have a method also defined in the header file. When I call that method from another class, the method works is called and works just fine until it reaches `oldLabel.text = finalString;`. The label doesn't update. At first I thought it may have been that my tableView wasn't reloading so I reloaded it when the method was called but still nothing. The label doesn't change at all. I've also set breakpoints and even logged the labels text after changing but the log just returns null. Here is the code for the method.

```
-(void)changInteractBasedOnRow:(NSInteger)integer {
    NSLog(@"Passed");
    int finalInt = integer * 2;
    NSString *finalString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", finalInt];
    oldLabel.text = finalString;
}
```

Comment: if you put a NSLog for finalString? is nil or not?

Comment: @Ilario I have yes. It returns 0 not nil but that's because integer is 0. Not nil.

Comment: ok, then says @Antonio MG controls connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well is quite hard to check your problem with just that little piece of code, but I'll try to put you in the right direction.

Your code looks fine, so:

Put a log in oldLabel, is it nil? (not oldLabel.text, oldLabel) Then check that your outlet is connected correctly, probably not.

Your method is correct, and unless you are calling in from a secondary thread that is not upadting the UI, it should work if everything is connected properly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My problem was that I was updating my table incorrectly but I found the hole. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

With the little piece of code that you have provided, I can be sure that the problem resides in the way you declare your IBOutlet.

Can you cross check & make sure that you are determining the ownership on the `oldLabel`. In case it if it is missing, you may not be able to update the label.

`@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *oldLabel;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to first check the outlet of label properly if connected then try this code :

```
oldLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", finalString];
```